# sha256_crypt.encrypt always returning another hash

Tags: python, encryption, sha256

I am developing a webapp using python and flask. It has a user system, so, of course, a registration form. I am using, to encrypt the password of the user that wants to registrate, passlib.hash.sha256 . Here's what I am doing:

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt as sha256
[...]
if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    confirm_password = request.form['confirm_password'] 
    email = request.form['email']

    password = sha256.encrypt(password) #Encryption.



    c, conn = connection('accounts') #Connection to the database


    x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts  WHERE username = '%s' OR email = '%s'" %(thwart(username), thwart(email)))

    if x:
        flash("We are very sorry, but this Username/Email-address is already taken. Please try again")
    else:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s")' %(thwart(username), thwart(password), thwart(email)))
        conn.commit()
        flash('Succesfully Registered!')
```

In the database, the hash is always varying, even if the same password has been inputed. Does anybody know why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have found out about the concept of salt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography). Are you sure that you are qualified enough to handle the authentication?

Comment: What do you mean by "qualified"

Comment: I see. But I didn't program anything that would add random data. Is this new to python's sha256?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fristly, please note that `sha256_crypt.encrypt(..)` is deprecated since version 1.7 and is instead renamed to `sha256_crypt.hash(..)` so you have

```
hash = sha256_crypt.hash("password")
```

for creating the hash. As the hash includes a random salt, you can't recalculate the hash and compare, instead you should lookup the hash in the table, and then use it in a `sha256_crypt.verify()` like:

```
sha256_crypt.verify("password", hash)
```

Comment: is _hash_ representing the hash that is extracted from the database or the built-in type `hash`?

Comment: The statement: `hash = sha256_crypt.hash("password")` I took directly from the documentation. The first `hash` is the outcome of a calculation done by the `hash(..)` methode call, and is what needs to be kept in the database.

Answer (score 1):

check your database structure. 
sha256 may require upto 70 values.
Increase the password field to about 100 values.

Answer (score -2):

Try [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto).sha256 instead, passlib seems not the the right solution for your requirement to compute an unsalted hash.